# Counting the number of consecutive 3s in a 2D list

Tags: python, python-2.7

My dataset which I imported into python as a list:

[image: My dataset which I imported into python as a list]

Is there a way I can count the largest number of consecutive 3s? Like in the first row, the output should be 5 as there are 5 consecutive 3s.

```
import csv
r = csv.reader(open('motor.csv'))
list_r = list(r)


for row in list_r:
    print
    count = 0
    for col in row:
        if col == '3' and row[row.index(col)+1] == '3':
            count+=1

print count
```

This is the code I wrote but I seem to get incorrect output.

Comment: post the actual value of list_r as a literal in the code, so we don't need motor.csv for [mcve] It looks like you are counting the quantity of adjacent pairs of two's in the same row. That's not what I would think of if someone asks me to found the most consecutive 3's. Also you reset the count after each row, but you don't print the result until done.

Comment: Consider what the value of `row.index(col)` will be when there is more than one `'3'` in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `itertools.groupby` to break the list into sub-sequences of identical values. Then simply return the maximum length of the sub-sequences.

```
from itertools import groupby
list_r = [
    ['3','3','3','3','3','1','3','3','5'],
    ['1','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','1','3','3','5','3'],
    ['3','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','1','3','3','5'],
]

result = [
    max(len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(row) if k == '3')
    for row in list_r
]

assert result == [5, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

They to use the following as a guide:

```
import itertools

def consecutive(group):
    first, second = itertools.tee(group)
    second.next()
    for first, second in itertools.izip(first, second):
        if second != first + 1:  return False
    return True

def iterate_submatrix(matrix, t, l):
    '''yield the horizontals and diagonals of 4x4  subsection of matrix starting at t(op), l(eft) as 4-tuples'''
    submat =  [row[l:l+4] for row in matrix[t:t+4]]
    for r in submat: yield tuple(r)  
    for c in range (0,4):     
        yield tuple(r[c] for r in submat)
    yield tuple(submat[rc][rc] for rc in range (0,4))
    yield tuple(submat[rc][3-rc] for rc in range(0,4))

for item in iterate_submatrix(test_matrix, 0,0):
     print item, consecutive(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `row.index(col)` will always produce the index of the *first* value of `col` in the row. This is clearly not what was intended. Instead, I'd recommend using `enumerate` to iterate over the values and indices in the row at the same time.

Second, you are only tracking the current number of consecutive 3's, and there is no code to track the maximum of this count value. Adding another variable and an `else` clause to your code can resolve this.

```
for row in list_r:
    max_count = current_count = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(row[:-1]):
        if value == '3' and row[index+1] == '3':
            current_count += 1
        else:
            max_count = max(current_count, max_count)
            current_count = 0
    print count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

data = [
    ['1', '2', '2', '3', '5', '6'],
    ['1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5'],
    ['1', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4']
]

max = 0
for item in data:
    match = re.search(r'3+', "".join(item))

try:

    if len(str(match.group(0))) > max:
        max = len(str(match.group(0)))
except AttributeError:
    pass

print(max)
```